# Define an empty Q.Promise<void>

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, q

I am new to Q and promises. I have a simple interface that I want to implement. To focus the question, I simplified the interface and its implemenration:

```
declare interface NavigatableViewModel extends ViewModel {
    readonly loadPromise: Q.Promise<void>;
}

export default class FormViewModel implements NavigatableViewModel  {
    public readonly loadPromise: Q.Promise<void>;

    constructor() {
        this.loadPromise = Q();
    }
}
```

The line "this.loadPromise = Q()" is throwing an exception with the following details: 
ReferenceError: Q is not defined at FormViewModel...

How can I define an empty Q.Promise?

Comment: You didn't import `Q` in the code above.

Comment: This resolved the error. It is weird that this has not been caught at compilation time. I am adding an answer. If you add an answer, I will delete mine and mark yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing Q worked:

```
import * as Q from "q";
```